# How to debug: uWSGI Error Python application not found. And how to set up uwsgi logging

Tags: logging, nginx, pyramid, uwsgi, python-3.2

I'm running `nginx`, `uwsgi` and `pyramid`.

I know that the error is due to something in my `production.ini` file but I'm not entirely sure what. I'm not so keen to guess what the problem is, I would much rather have a meaningful error message.

- /var/log/uwsgi/app/my_app_log is filled with info about how many bytes were sent when.
- /var/log/nginx/access.log is empty
- /var/log/nginx/error.log is empty

Now apparently I can configure uwsgi to log things in an actually friendly way. I know there are logging options, I just don't know how to use them. Google isn't helping me out on this one.

So my question is:

How would I get `uwsgi` to log errors produced by errors in my `pyramid` app's `production.ini` file?

/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/mega_capture.co.za.xml looks like:

```
<uwsgi>
    <plugin>python3</plugin>
    <socket>/run/uwsgi/app/mega_capture.co.za/mega_capture.co.za.socket</socket>
    <pythonpath>/srv/www/mega_capture.co.za/application/</pythonpath>
    <virtualenv>/srv/www/mega_capture.co.za/application/venv/</virtualenv>
    <app mountpoint="/">
        <script>wsgi_configuration_module</script>
    </app>
    <master/>
    <processes>4</processes>
    <harakiri>60</harakiri>
    <reload-mercy>8</reload-mercy>
    <cpu-affinity>1</cpu-affinity>
    <stats>/tmp/stats.socket</stats>
    <max-requests>2000</max-requests>
    <limit-as>512</limit-as>
    <reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
    <reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
    <no-orphans/>
    <vacuum/>
</uwsgi>
```

/srv/www/mega_capture.co.za/application/wsgi_configuration_module.py looks like:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/mega_capture.co.za/application')
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/mega_capture.co.za/.python-egg'

from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini_path = '/srv/www/mega_capture.co.za/application/venv/pyramidapp/production.ini'

setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```